# Estoy intentando guardar dos formularios en django y me sale el error 'function' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    numero_identificacion = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)
    fecha_Nacimiento = models.DateField()
    lugar_nacimiento = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    fecha_Expedicion = models.DateField()
    lugar_expedicion = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    nombre1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    nombre2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    apellido1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    apellido2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    celular = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    correo = models.EmailField(max_length=240)

class Solicitud(models.Model):   
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    valor_solicitado = models.BigIntegerField()
    valor_aprobado = models.BigIntegerField()
    numero_cuotas = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=NUM_CUOTAS)
    dia_pago = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=DIAS_PAGO)
    estado_solicitud = models.ForeignKey(Estado_solicitud, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tipo_credito = models.ForeignKey(Tipo_credito, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    clientes = models.ManyToManyField(Cliente, through='Actores', through_fields=('cliente', 'solicitud'),)
    fecha_creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    fecha_modificacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    usuario_crea = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usuario_modifica = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.pk)

class Actores(models.Model):
    solicitud = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Solicitud, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    codeudor1 = models.IntegerField()
    codeudor2 = models.IntegerField()
    codeudor3 = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['solicitud']


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.pk)
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
class Crear_solicitud_view(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Solicitud
    template_name = 'credito/solicitud/crear_solicitud.html'
    form_class = Solictud_form
    form_actores = Actores_form
    success_url = reverse_lazy('cliente:listar_clientes')
    login_url = "bases:login"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        contexto = super(Crear_solicitud_view, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #print('contextp',contexto)

        if 'form1' not in contexto:
            contexto['form1'] = self.form_class(self.request.GET)

        if 'form2' not in contexto:
            contexto['form2'] = self.form_actores(self.request.GET)


        return contexto


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object
        form1 = self.form_class(request.POST)
        form2 = self.form_actores(request.POST)

        clientes = Cliente.objects.all()
        #print(form2)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            actores = form2.save(commit=False)
            actores.solicitud = form1.save()
            actores.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            print('hola')
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form1=form1, form2=form2))
```

**Error:**

```
    Internal Server Error: /credito/nuevo_solicitud/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/haroldtg/Documents/Desarrollo/shigab/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/haroldtg/Documents/Desarrollo/shigab/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/haroldtg/Documents/Desarrollo/shigab/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/haroldtg/Documents/Desarrollo/shigab/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/haroldtg/Documents/Desarrollo/shigab/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/haroldtg/Documents/Desarrollo/shigab/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/haroldtg/Documents/Desarrollo/shigab/shigab/apps/credito/views.py", line 56, in post
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form1=form1, form2=form2))
  File "/Users/haroldtg/Documents/Desarrollo/shigab/shigab/apps/credito/views.py", line 23, in get_context_data
    contexto = super(Crear_solicitud_view, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/haroldtg/Documents/Desarrollo/shigab/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 66, in get_context_data
    kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
  File "/Users/haroldtg/Documents/Desarrollo/shigab/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 33, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
  File "/Users/haroldtg/Documents/Desarrollo/shigab/shigab/apps/credito/forms.py", line 37, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/haroldtg/Documents/Desarrollo/shigab/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 292, in __init__
    object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
  File "/Users/haroldtg/Documents/Desarrollo/shigab/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 82, in model_to_dict
    opts = instance._meta
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: Primero que nada el error ocurre en el archivo `forms.py`, específicamente en el método `__init__`, algo mal estas haciendo ahí, de ser posible actualiza tu pregunta con los forms. Por otra parte la relación `solicitud` del modelo `Actores` espera una instancia del modelo `Cliente`, en la vista le estas pasando una instancia del modelo `Solicitud`, lo cual dará error. A lo mejor te equivocaste al momento de crear la relación `solicitud` en el modelo `Actores`, lo mas lógico es que se relacione con el modelo `Solicitud` y no con el modelo `Cliente`, según el nombre de la relación.

Comment: Gracias. Me ayudo mucho tu orientación. Tenia un error en el formulario

Comment: Un gusto poder ayudarte!